# Coordinate Transformations for Schwarzschild Metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

What are the general transformation equations, i.e. relation between $x'$ & $x$, $t'$ & $t$ required for Schwarzschild metric, e.g. Lorentz transformations give Minkowski metric, what transformations will give Schwarzschild metric? i.e. How to derive jacobian matrix from a metric tensor?

Comment: I don't knwo what you mean by "derive jacobian from a metric". Do you mean the volume element, $\sqrt{|\det g|}\,d^4x$?

Comment: Thanks Adam for the reply, by jacobian I meant jacobian matrix, the one constructed from coordinate transformations. Now metric tensor is nothing but product of jacobian matrix with its transpose, so I was wondering if it is possible to get the jacobian matrix & in turn the respective coordinate transformations from a given metric tensor.

Comment: No, metric tensor is generaly NOT a product of jacobian matrices. You can find a metric tensor in one set of coordinates using the jacobian matrixes and a metric tensor in another coordinates, but you need some metrc tensor to start with.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the crucial insight.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that "Lorentz transformation give Minkowski metric"; the correct way of looking at it is that Lorentz transformations are symmetries of Minkowski spacetime, that is some transformations do not change the metric. But it's not that the metric is given by them. Minkowski spacetime is very symmetric and it has 10-dimensional group of symmetries (4 translations, 3 rotations, 3 boosts), but it's not the only metric with this property, de Sitter's space also has just as many symmetries. Schwarzschild metric is much less symmetric and it has only 4 symmetries: the time translation and 3 rotations. The most general metric that has these symmetries can be written as (in appropriate coordinates):
$$ g = f_1(r) dt^2 - f_2(r) dr^2 - r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$
Functions $f_1(r)$ and $f_2(r)$ can only be found by solving Einstein's equation of General Relativity, and then we get Schwarzschild metric.

Note, Schwarzschild metric is not just a Minkowski metric after some change of coordinates. No transformation of coordinates of flat space will give you the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: Could you please explicitly write the transformation law of the time coordinate , that was asked in the question... that is the relation between $t'$ and $t$ under the Schwarzschild metric?

Comment: As I said, Schwarzschild metric has no boost symmetry, which means there's no transformation analogous to Minkowski's $x' = \gamma(x-\beta t)$, $t' = \gamma(t-\beta x) $ that would preserve the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: I have another request. Could you please clarify it: in a Minkowski space, an inertial observer would have a straight line as describing his motion and all his clocks along this line would read the same time. My question is: For a non inertial observer in a curved space, what is the substitute for his constant time coordinate (which exists for an inertial observer),that is what is the time that each clock at every point on his curve of motion reads? Could you maybe give me the mention of a source where I can learn more about this from?

Comment: Just a note, that should be a separate question, comments are not the place to have aditional questions. That's for the sake of other users, who may have similar questions and qould seek answers - they're not likely to find tyhem if they are hidden in comments. But to answer it briefly, in there's no THE time coordinate defined by a given observer, there are several ways coordinates can be defined for them. They happen to coincide in flat space (giving standard Minkowski coordinates), bot not in the general. You can look up for example Fermi coordinates and Riemann normal coordinates.